# Table blinking when autorefresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

My table was blinking in every 5 second because of this auto refresh script in my php page. here is my code for auto refresh

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#autorefresh');
    // refresh every 5 seconds
    var refresher = setInterval(function(){
      table.load("utility_autorefresh.php");
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(refresher);
    }, 5000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This only happen in firefox browser

Comment: so what's the question here?

Comment: i want to stop that blinking in my page in every 5 second but i want auto refresh in every 5 second

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `.load()`, you can try using `$.get()` or `$.post()` to get the new content, then use `.html()` to put it into the table.

```
var refresher = setInterval(function(){
    $.post("utility_autorefresh.php",function(dom) { table.html(dom); });
}, 5000);
```

let see if it working and not blinking anymore.